# How to apply max function in a join query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am new to SQL Server, I have 3 tables  consider an employee table

| empid | name | location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | USA |
| 2 | efg | UK |

Another table named location-table

| location | holidaycode |
| --- | --- |
| uk | uk1 |
| usa | usa1 |

And also `holidaytable`:

| holiday-code | date | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| uk1 | 2022-01-01 | LM |
| uk1 | 2022-01-01 | RMC |

Expected result is:

| empid | location | holidaycode | date | type 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | uk | uk1 | 2022-01-01 | RMC |

suppose I query the tables based on empid and date  say ,the holidays available for empid 2 from a particular from date such that on a particular day (2022-01-01) I have LM and RMC on that day , I need only RMC ,if RMC is not available else LMC.

Comment: `MAX` works the same if you are using 1 table in the `FROM`, or many. What did you try? Why didn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
select e.empid, e.location, h.holidaycode, [date], max([type])
from employee e inner join location_table l 
                           on e.location=l.location
                inner join holidaytable h 
                           on l.holidaycode=h.holidaycode
where e.empid=2 and h.[date]='2022-01-01'
group by e.empid, e.location, h.holidaycode, [date]
```

Example:

Schema and insert statements:

```
   create table employee(empid int, name varchar(50), location varchar(50));
   insert into employee values(1,   'abc',  'USA');
   insert into employee values(2,   'efg',  'UK');
   
   create table location_table(location varchar(50),holidaycode varchar(50));
   insert into location_table values('uk','uk1');
   insert into location_table values('usa','usa1');
   
   create table holidaytable(holidaycode    varchar(50), [date] date, [type] varchar(50));
   insert into holidaytable values('uk1',   '2022-01-01',   'LM');
   insert into holidaytable values('uk1',   '2022-01-01',   'RMC');
```

Query:

```
 select e.empid, e.location, h.holidaycode, [date], max([type]) [type 1]
   from employee e inner join location_table l 
                              on e.location=l.location
                   inner join holidaytable h 
                              on l.holidaycode=h.holidaycode
   where e.empid=2 and h.[date]='2022-01-01'
   group by e.empid, e.location, h.holidaycode, [date]
```

Output:

| empid | location | holidaycode | date | type 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | UK | uk1 | 2022-01-01 | RMC |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6e1c2a56b69748b4cabc0e529799130a)*

Comment: how we select a particular employee on a specific holiday date.

Comment: @userb I have revised my answer. Please check.

Comment: Still not getting the result correctly ,  showing both types on the same date

Comment: It's working on sample data. Please check the example.

Comment: You are most welcome @userb. Best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to get only the first row of each grouping.

Either do `ORDER BY type DESC` or use `ORDER BY CASE WHEN type = 'RMC' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END`

```sql
SELECT
  e.empid,
  e.location,
  l.holidaycode,
  h.date,
  h.type
FROM employee e
JOIN location l ON l.location = e.location
JOIN (
    SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY h.holidaycode, h.date ORDER BY h.type DESC)
    FROM holiday h
) h ON h.holidaycode = l.holidaycode AND h.rn = 1
WHERE h.date = '2022-01-01';
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dc0c65c1db50545a6511a7d3947d9481)